# Which is more efficient, CGContextEOClip or setting layer.mask?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm masking a layer in a non rectangular shape. What's the most efficient method, overriding drawRect: and using CGContextEOClip with a custom made path, or not overriding drawRect: but setting layer.mask using a CALayer made from the same path?

Alternatively, are there any more efficient ways of masking a layer?